# Switching database from MySQL to MSSQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, web-applications

I have seen a lot of examples that are switching from `MSSQL` to `MySQL` but in my case I have been using `MySQL` and I would like to switch it to `MSSQL`. I have previously added the following line in my `DbContext` to make `MySQL` work.

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration))]
```

To use `MSSQL`, I've commented out the line I've added in my `DbContext`. Also I have replaced the `MySQL` connection string with the following connection string.

```
    <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial 
    Catalog=WebApplication;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"/>
```

However, I'm getting error as shown below.

> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a
>   configuration file required to service this request. Please review the
>   specific error details below and modify your configuration file
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Unrecognized attribute 'name'.
>
> Line 92: remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" name="MySQL Data
>   Provider"

Does it mean that I have to remove and uninstall all `MySQL` nuget package to be able to use `MSSQL`?

Comment: Right, you need to remove/comment all sections inside `<DbProviderFactories>` under `<system.data>` element, then remove/comment `<provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient">` lines under `<entityFramework>`. Also try remove all references regarding `MySql.Data` on your project.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Thanks. Your solution works.